# Disk partition interrupted

Tags: macos, hard-drive, disk-utility

So I was partitioning my macbook's hard disk so as to install addition operating system.

But as disk utility was in the process of partitioning, I closed the disk partition (for a reason) thinking it wont save the changes and I will start again.

Big mistake.

All the free space (a lot) I had before is now showing as "other" and the disk isn't partitioned. How do I fix this? Thanks!

Comment: It might be useful to know which OS version you are running, too.

Comment: Please clarify, you were attempting to partition a "portion" of the free space and interrupted the process. Now all the previously free space is showing as "other"?

Comment: yes. so say i had 200 gb to remaining on my computer, after this incident, it had 10 gb. I am using OS X 10.9

Answer (score 1):

If the formerly-free space is showing up as 'other', the implication is that your current system partition is perfectly OK?

I would recommend to start with, booting from the Recovery partition, and doing a 'Verify Disk' and/or 'Repair Disk' on the system partition.

Is the 'other' space actually a partition, or is it free unpartitioned space on the drive?

If it's a partition, you can use Disk Utility to select that partition and use 'Erase' it in the format you wanted - give it the name you want at the same time.

If not, you can just create the new partition in that space.

Comment: the disk isnt partitioned. In a way, the entire thing kind of filled up my hard disk rather than partitioning it.

Comment: Then I hope you have a backup of everything you had on that drive - it sounds like it's all gone ...